# Using regex expression in XCUIElement

Tags: xcuitest

In my test app, I don't have a11y identifier set for a button and the a11y label for the button would change based on the response from server. I have created a regex expression for the validation but not sure how to use the regex regression to validate the element, I tried something like below

```
func testApp() {
let pattern = "User, [A-Za-z0-9]+, will start in [0-9]+ min"
return app.buttons[pattern].firstMatch()
}
```

The test fails with the above function, failing to identify the element. Does anyone have any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0):

You should assign an accessibility identifier and then assert the label to test your case properly.

If you still want to use regex, you can use

```swift
app.buttons.allElementsBoundByIndex.filter { 
   $0.label.matches(regex)
}
```

This line will return an array of `XCUIElements`.
You will need this `String` extension

```swift
extension String {
    func matches(_ regex: String) -> Bool {
        return self.range(of: regex, options: .regularExpression, range: nil, locale: nil) != nil
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of using `filter`, you may want to use `first`. But, I agree with this answer.